# reshape long format data to wide format using row names as column headers

Tags: r, reshape, spread

I have checked out the following questions on StackOverFlow and links to other R help books:

[R: Reshape Data Long to Wide - understanding reshape parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237554/r-reshape-data-long-to-wide-understanding-reshape-parameters)

[Reshape long to wide with multiple groupings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620492/reshape-long-to-wide-with-multiple-groupings)

[How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r)

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

I want to take my data which is in long format (two columns, with 6200 entries) with non-unique names in column "id" with different sequences in "sequence" and reshape into a wide format where the column headers are now the "id" with all of the sequences from "sequence" listed underneath each id.

```
          id    sequence
1   CK1alpha TPSIAsDISLP
2   CK1alpha IASDIsLPIAT
3       CDK1 SVPSSsPGTSV
4       CDK1 EGCQGsPQRRG
5   CK1alpha DICEDsDIDGD
6 PKCepsilon IHGSDsVKSAE
```

What I would like to get:

```
id          CK1alpha    CDK1        PKCepsilon
sequence    TPSIAsDISLP SVPSSsPGTSV
            IASDIsLPIAT EGCQGsPQRRG
            DICEDsDIDGD
```

I have tried to use `reshape`

```
kinase_sub_wide <- reshape(kinase_substrate, idvar = "id", timevar = "sequence", direction = "wide")
```

However I get warning messages saying multiple rows match:

```
Warning messages:
1: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar,  ... :
  multiple rows match for sequence=TPSIAsDISLP: first taken
2: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar,  ... :
  multiple rows match for sequence=IASDIsLPIAT: first taken
3: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar,  ... :
  multiple rows match for sequence=RSQSRsNSPLP: first taken
```

I have also tried to use `spread`

```
kinase_substrate_wide <- spread(kinase_substrate, id, sequence)
```

but get errors with duplicate identifiers:

```
> kinase_substrate_wide <- spread(kinase_substrate, id, sequence)
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1812, 1813, 4469), (906, 3349), (253,     285, 2114, 2174, 3022, 4385, 4501), (155, 203, 218, 261, 316, 542, 682, 1021, 1123, 1238, 1492, 1919, 1938, 1997, 2064, 2139, 2323, 2387, 2597, 2826, 3058, 3377, 3899, 4024, 4135, 4241, 4314, 4617, 4733, 5055, 5289, 5467, 5726, 5952, 6165), (72, 272, 749, 1100, 2792, 3573, 3858, 4254, 4257), (209, 548, 637, 653, 1034, 1038, 1213, 1387, 1445, 1475, 1476, 1692, 1735, 2635, 3180, 4005, 4661, 4988, 5672, 5870, 6042), (21, 1802), (23, 24, 30, 49, 60, 86, 122, 127, 137, 177, 182, 227, 250, 260, 268, 270, 299, 347, 356, 361, 400, 424, 425, 448, 483, 488, 494, 509, 510, 512, 522, 523, 524, 540, 559, 572, 612, 614, 616, 622, 720, 750, 774, 794, 816, 820, 829, 866, 868, 912, 916, 918, 940, 946, 955, 962, 984, 992, 1004, 1013, 1054, 1055, 1070, 1073, 1083, 1086, 1105, 1140, 1154, 1164, 1179, 1222, 1228, 1230, 1284, 1295, 1316, 1318, 1333, 1334, 1348, 1356, 1375, 1383, 1389, 1390, 1406, 1421, 1444, 1458, 1473, 1474, 1490
```

How can I use either of the functions above in order to get the data into wide format and bring each sequence that it corresponds under the column of the id?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT #1

Using the suggestion to include an index from David's comment gets me there

```
reshape(transform(df, indx = ave(as.character(id), id, FUN = seq)), idvar = "indx", timevar = "id", direction = "wide")
```

resulting in this:

```
   indx sequence.CK1alpha sequence.CDK1 sequence.PKCepsilon sequence.GRK2 sequence.ICK sequence.CDK5 sequence.PKCbeta sequence.PAK1 sequence.GSK3beta
1     1       TPSIAsDISLP   SVPSSsPGTSV         IHGSDsVKSAE   DIDESsPGTEW  VDRLQsEPESI   AQAPSsPRVTE      GAQAPsSPRVT   AQERPsQAAPA       NIDNLsPKASH
2     2       IASDIsLPIAT   EGCQGsPQRRG         KLSGLsFKRNR   EKKEEsEESDD  DNRVPsPPPTG   PAEVKsPEKAK      DESTGsIAKRL   RSRTPsASNDD       FNYNPsPRKSS
5     3       DICEDsDIDGD   TLNSGsPEKTC         TALAPsTMKIK   EESEEsDDDMG  PDTKDsPVCPH   QKPAAsPRPRR      IVENLsSRCSW   KQKVDsLLENL       SSGAKsPSKSG
7     4       TFEDLsDVEGG   HVAVSsPTPET         VAKRLsLTMGG   MNSSIsSGSGS  LKVEGsPTEEA   DFTCGsPTAAG      YPVSPsDKVLI   RALRAsESGI_       FPDDLsLDHSD
16    5       PRSGRsPTGNT   TEVPRsPKHAH         EKLVLsKLYEE   RPTSIsWDGLD  ESERGsGSQSS   SDTVTsPQRAG      EKKVVsLNGEL   PGSPLsSQPVL       YSDSIsPFNKS
29    6       MSDTGsPGMQR   KYSPTsPTYSP         EILNRsPRNRK   KNRPTsISWDG         <NA>   GRGAEsPFEEK      LVNSAsAQKRS   SSKTAsLPGYG       PSRTAsFSESR
```

EDIT #2

Is there are way in the reshape function to avoid putting in "sequence." in front of each name? Or will I have to turn to a regex to rename all of the column names?

EDIT #3

Used `gsub` to remove `"sequence."` from the column names and assigned it to a variable:

```
new_col_names <- names(DF) <- gsub("sequence.", "", names(DF))
```

followed by applying the `new_col_names` to the data frame

```
colnames(DF) <- new_col_names
```

Thanks for helping me out everyone!

Comment: You have to try `dcast(df, sequence ~ id, value.var = "sequence")`, of the `reshape2` package. The result will be slightly different than the expected but to be honest it is a great thing because your expected output it is not only obscure but also non sense.

Comment: If you want to use `reshape`, you will probably need to add an index, for instance `reshape(transform(df, indx = ave(as.character(id), id, FUN = seq)), idvar = "indx", timevar = "id", direction = "wide")`

Comment: I should note that I am stuck with the output format that I would like. The program that I am trying to prepare the data for input takes the data in this way...

Comment: @SabDeM I tried using `dcast` in this case but the result is a data frame with 128 columns (id) and 5233 rows (sequence)

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks David that did the trick! the next step would be to remove "sequence." from the beginning of the each id. is there a way that i can incorporate this into the reshape function or will i have to use regex in order to remove this from the column header? thanks again.

Comment: You have to manually rename after the reshaping.

Comment: To remove sequence in all column names: `names(reshapedf) <- gsub("sequence.", "", names(reshapedf))`

Comment: What do you intend on doing with this? A list might be more useful for further analysis.

Comment: @JeremyS I will have a wide format data frame with a list of potential sequences that match an enzyme...this is the format for a database file that is used for a gene-set enrichment analysis type application and that's what I have to work with.